# AngularJS: Click and pass an entire object from one page to another page

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am building an application with AngularJS.

I have already build dynamically this table with the data of each users:

```
<div ng-controller="contactsCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                <td><div ng-click="{{contact}}"> Edit</div></td>
                <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.adresse}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
                <td><a href="mailto:{{contact.email}}"> Email</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I added a button **Edit** with a **ng-click={{contact.name}}** associated on it. When I click in that button I want the info of the selected user to be shown in the following form in order to edit and afterwards save the new data.

```
<div ng-controller='detailsCtrl'>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <h2>{{contact.name}}</h2>
        <address>
            <p>{{contact.adresse}}</p>
            <p>{{contact.adresse}}</p>
            <p>{{contact.phone}}</p>
            <p>{{contact.email}}</p>

        </address>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I pass the object (with all the properties: name, addresse, telefone and email) from the button in table (contactsCtrl) to the form (DetailsCtrl)?

I have read and listened tons of tutorials but I am getting more and more confused. please help

Answer (score 0):

You would want to have a service common in both controllers OR you can do a broadcast/emit between controlers. After that, pass entire object in ng-click i.e. rather than ng-click={{contact.name}}  you can do ng-click="passContact(contact);"

and in  passContact function pass object by broadcast/emit OR service.

Create a small fiddle with your code if you want to get code for this.